# How to enable vim mode in RStudio

Tags: ide, rstudio

Has anyone been able to enable or use vim mode in RStudio? I'm using a new version of RStudio, (3.3.2 (2016-10-31)). The only instructions are from three or four years ago, and the screenshot of the GUI is different than what I use. (tools->global options->code->editing). There's no checkbox to enable it. I am very hopeful that it still exists

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is what RStudio support team says:

[Switching to Vim Editing Mode](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208492728-Vim-Editing-Mode)

The option is under options->code->editing->keybindings, from the dropdown select Vim.

Comment: The option has changed to tools -> global options -> code -> keybindings

Comment: It seems that I cannot map the shortcut jj/jk to <esc> permanently, then I thought the vim mode loses its convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Posit only support a light way vim mode, labelled as "Vim Keybindings":
tools -> global options -> [image: code -> editing -> keybindings -> Vim]